# Remove mail merge data source from MS Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, mail-merge

I am using Microsoft Word 2013. 
I have a document that, when opened, prompts me with:

> Opening this document will run the following SQL command:
>   SELECT * FROM C:\somepath\somefile.mrg
>   Data from your database will be placed in the document.  Do you want to continue?

I am trying to find where in the Word document this data source is being specified, and hopefully remove it completely.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In many (if not all) cases, answering "No" to this prompt should be enough to disconnect the data source. But you should then save the document, and try opening it again.

If that doesn't work, try to get to the point where the document is open, then open the Mailings tab, click the **Start Mail Merge** button in the **Start Mail Merge** group, then select **Normal Word Document** from the dropdown. Then save the document.

If you don't save the document after disconnecting the data source, the problem will recur.

Comment: When I tried to do this it greyed out the Insert Merge Field menu...

Comment: @Steph - when the document has no data source, the Insert Merge Field menu will indeed be greyed out. In order to get it back, you have to connect the document to a data source again. There used to be a feature that let you connect to a "header source" to allow the user to use the field dropdown even though no data source was connected, but .docx format does not support header source properly so it is generally simpler to assume that that approach no longer works.

Comment: ☝ You may also need to change _anything_ else about your document (e.g. adding and then deleting a character) for the saving to be effective.

Answer (score 2):

This took me eternity so I thought I'd post an answer as well.

In my case I had to remove the old template document, which triggered the query.

This is possible in the developer tools menu, on the very right.

Comment: Same in my case (Word 365) - Word always wanted to process an SQL query because the document had an deprecated mail merge document as template. Using the "Normal Word Document" in the "Start Mail Merge" group does *not* solve the problem in that case. Thanks @SandroKGS for giving this hint here!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to un-merge the data - keep the document as a mailmerge but not show peoples' specific details in the document each time I opened it. I finally was able to do this by going through the mailmerge wizard, and when it came to selecting recipients with the little checkboxes, unchecking all of them. When I closed the wizard it looked like a mailmerge form again without individual data; I saved it as a new document to maintain this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Word 2010, open the document, click on the Mailings tab, click the down arrow under the Start Mail Merge button, click on Normal Word Document. This will disconnect the Word document from the source document.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with a previous post, here is a little adjustment.

Answering "No" to this prompt was not enough to disconnect the data source. Go to the Mailings tab, click the Start Mail Merge button in the Start Mail Merge group, then select **Normal Word Document** from the dropdown. Then save the document.
If you don't save the document after disconnecting the data source, obiously the problem will recur.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler fix.

- Open the merge document
- At the prompt to run the query answer `no`. The document displays with no data.
- Use `Save as` to save the document to the same folder using the same name
- When prompted to overwrite the original say `yes`

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already got well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score -2):

Go to File then-> Options then-> Trust Center then-> Trust Center Settings then->  Privacy Options then-> Document Inspector then-> Inspect and then remove XML data.